# Setting logging level through CLI argument? Java

Tags: java, logging, command-line-arguments

Quick question,

Looking through these examples which statically assign the logging level of a program

http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/19/log.html?page=2

http://www.vogella.com/articles/Logging/article.html

How can I dynamically set the logging level through an argument when I call my Java application

e.g.

> java -jar myprogram.jar FINE

Meaning that instead of this code

```
 logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

I could have something like

```
logger.setLevel(args[0]);
```

When researching the documentation there doesnt appear to be away to set the log level with a string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use builtin method [`Level.parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), which parses a level name string into a `Level`.

> The argument string may consist of either a level name or an integer
>   value.

For example:

- "SEVERE"
- "INFO"
- "1000"

Comment: Will need to be careful about user input for this but thank you :)

Comment: @serupticious User input validation is mandatory no matter how you implement it. Btw, with this you get new levels created when you use integers which do not map to a known `Level`. You might be able to use this to your advantage.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Map of String and Level and refer to that:

```
logger.setLevel(logmap.get(args[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The Level class is the reference:

```
    public static final Level INFO = new Level("INFO", 800, defaultBundle);
```

You could map from a String like `"INFO"` to some constant like `Level.INFO` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `map` to store the `Level` mappings:

```
Map<String, Level> levelmap = new HashMap<String, Level>();
levelmap.put("info", Level.INFO);
```

and then use this map to set the log level:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger rootLogger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger();
String level = arg[0];
rootLogger.setLevel(levelmap.get(level));
```

Comment: It does not look like he is using Log4j.